# Configurate an error for a custom command and conditions

Tags: macros, conditionals, logging

Is there a way to allow custom command to send a log entry who pointed to an error ?

I want to create the command `\difficulty` who convert the four first integers in filled or emptied stars. Here is the code :

```
\newcommand{\difficulty}[1]{
    \ifnum#1=1
        \ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}\ding{73}
    \else
        \ifnum#1=2
            \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}
        \else
            \ifnum#1=3
                \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}
            \else
                \ifnum#1=4
                    \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}
                \else
                    undefined
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi}
```

However, i want to alert if the argument is not {1,2,3,4} by a message in the log-console. All i achieved untill now is to send an error if the argument is not a number (thanks to `\ifnum`). I'm totally lost to interact with the console and to create an alert.

Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\difficulty}[1]{
    \ifnum#1=1
    \ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}\ding{73}
    \else
    \ifnum#1=2
    \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}
    \else
    \ifnum#1=3
    \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}
    \else
    \ifnum#1=4
    \ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}
    \else
    undefined
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    Test for 1
    \difficulty{1}


    Test for 2
    \difficulty{2}

    Test for 3
    \difficulty{3}

    Test for 4
    \difficulty{4}

    Test for 25
    \difficulty{25}

    Test for 'random'
    \difficulty{random}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not directly related: Try `\ifcase#1 <case for 0>\or<case for 1>\or...\else<other cases>\fi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\isnum[1]{%
  \if!\ifnum9<1#1!\else_\fi\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\difficulty}[1]{%
  \isnum{#1}{%
    \ifcase#1
    \or\ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}\ding{73}
    \or\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}\ding{73}
    \or\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{73}
    \or\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}\ding{77}
    \else
      \typeout{difficulty: the number is not in 1..4 -> #1}%
    \fi
  }{\typeout{difficulty: the argument is not defined -> #1}}%
}

\begin{document}
    Test for 1
    \difficulty{1}

    Test for 2
    \difficulty{2}

    Test for 3
    \difficulty{3}

    Test for 4
    \difficulty{4}

    Test for 25
    \difficulty{25}

    Test for 'random'
    \difficulty{random}

\end{document}
```

writes to the console:

```
difficulty: the number is not in 1..4 -> 25
difficulty: the argument is not defined -> random
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: You've created `\isnum` but i do not understand what is the goal of this command. Could you expand it ? The construction with `\or` is also better. EDIT : After some test, the code does not work. He send no error neither with 25 nor random.
EDIT 2 : Ok, it is written in the .log file directly. My goal was to alert the user that there is an error to compile. (red line in the bottom window of texstudio/texmaker). I'm on Texstudio if it is important.

Comment: it tests if the argument is at least a number: 1a0 for example is not a number.

Comment: Thanks, clearer to me ! Do you know if it is possible to alert the user in the consol directly if there is an error ? Something like "line 18 error : 'random' is not a correct difficulty option". Otherwise, i think the question is solved !

Comment: `\errmessage{#1 is not a number!}`